# git undoing the changes

Tags: git, github

I have squashed 2 commits in my fork and had a pull request to master in github.

First commit has some formatting changes.

In my pull request, it is showing the formatting changes that I have done which I dont want to  be pushed to master.

Is there any way that I can have the pull request without showing those changes.

Comment: How have you squashed your commits?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new branch.

```
git checkout -b newbranch <commit-before-squashed-commits>
```

The cherry pick the one you want.  If you don't have the IDs, then look at `git reflog` to find them.

```
git cherry-pick <commit-id-of-one-you-want>
```

Then push that.